# How can I change the address nuxt/webpack is attempting to fetch subsequent chunks from?

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, bundles, webpack-config

My controller serves my nuxt app through another app's controller. e.g. hitting https://google.com/my-address will actually reach out to a nuxt app hosted at https://custom-address/. The initial load returns the server side render html and successfully hydrates the page by fetching the appropriate bundles from https://custom-address. However, subsequent navigation (https://google.com/my-address/another-address/) will attempt to fetch bundles from https://google.com/_nuxt/ instead of https://custom-address. Is there a way to configure this address in webpack/nuxt? I assume this would be a webpack specific configuration, but perhaps nuxt has a configuration for it as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the address where bundles are being served from with this `nuxt.config.js` setting: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build/#publicpath. A common use case for this would be serving your bundles through a cdn.